# jQuery Datatables, how hide specified column dynamically

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to hide some columns in datatable when page change size (responsive). I would like to show/hide some columns depending on curremt size.

Thank you.

Comment: Use [Responsive](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) extension, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45235750/3549014) below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is very simple.

```
var tbl = $('your_datatable_selector');

// Work with column 2
tbl.DataTable().column(2).visible(false); // or true, if you want to show it
```

Comment: This might be more helpful, http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.in/2015/08/jquery-datatable-show-hide-columns.html

Answer (score 2):

Use [Responsive](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) extension to show/hide columns dynamically based on screen size.

Optionally you can determine which columns will be hidden first using [`responsivePriority`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.responsivePriority) option, see [Column priority](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/priority) for more details.

Alternatively you can assign special classes to `th` elements to define column behavior, see [Class logic](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/classes) for more details.

You just need to include additional CSS/JS files and use [`responsive`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/responsive) option as shown below.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    responsive: true
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{

    var table = $(`'#screenFieldsTable'`).DataTable(); 
    
    // Hide two columns 
    
    table.columns( [10,11] ).visible( false );

}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?